# JavaFX. Shift elements in TilePane

Tags: java, swing, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

First of all, I have the `ScrollPane` and a large list of buttons. I need it to organize them in a 3x3 format and scroll through them. I think to do this with the `TilePane`. Correct me if it is possible to make this in a better way...
I have the following question:

How can I make a shift below the second row of buttons and all the following  when I press any button in the first row?

I want to do, by analogy with `TitledPane` and `Accordion`, but they are working with only one column.

Comment: What is a `TalePane`?

Comment: @fabian It's might be [TilePane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/TilePane.html) class.

Comment: Yes thanks! It TilePane, fixed.

Comment: 3x3 means you have 9 buttons? I think your question is not clear enough. Could you post a picture of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @warakawa Currently in my project I add many ImageView in TilePane. It is necessary that at a clique on a picture, there is a shift of all the other following pictures below, for example, 200px.